# Creating routes dynamically in Meteor

Tags: routes, meteor, meteorite

I'm using [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) package to set up routes in my app. However, I need to be able to set up some routes "dynamically". It means that I have some "static" routes and some "dynamic", which are changing depending on some variable (specifically part of URL).
For example, if user visits www.example.com/foo my routes should prefix all URLs with `foo`, if user visits www.example.com/bar, all routes should have `bar` prefix.

Pseudo code:

```
Meteor.subscribe('bar', function(){
  var prefix = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');

  // "dynamic" routes, generated after 'subscribe' is ready
  Meteor.Router.add({
    prefix+'/': function() {
      // some code
      return 'mainTemplate';
    },
    prefix+'/welcome': 'welcome',
    prefix+'/foo': 'foo',
    prefix+'/bar': 'bar'
  });
)};

// "static" routes, independent of current URL
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/': 'home',
  '/admin': 'admin'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're above set up should work, only change each route to have the `/` prefix

```
Routes = {}

Routes['/' + prefix + '/welcome'] = function() { return 'welcome' };
Routes['/' + prefix +' /foo'] = 'foo';
...

Meteor.Router.add(Routes);
```

Comment: It won't work that way. In your example, if I try to concatenate directly in `Meteor.Router.add()` method, I get an error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`. If I try to make this variable before `Meteor.Router.add()` and assign that var as some URL, nothing happens... In fact, my idea about "dynamic" setting up routes (after subscribe is ready) will probably not work as I was imagining, but still I cannot get this thing with prefix work in neither of my routes.

Comment: I've updated a bit, it should work using the `[]` way to declare the keys instead

Comment: Yap, that works now... I tried to use `[]` when defining my keys, but I tried to put them within the `Meteor.Router.add()`... Your solution occurred to me but I didn't actually tried it :) Thanks a lot!